# Create array positions as dynamic array in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I am so new with Matlab.
I have one dimension array *Table_cluster*.I am working in wireless sensor networks. So my concept is that all nodes will send data to associated cluster head.Cluster head will aggregate them.

Suppose

There are 5 nodes which are associated with cluster head 11.And each node will send 256 bytes of data.So cluster head will get 5*256 bytes data.I need to aggregate it.

This will apply to all 100 nodes and their associated cluster heads.

Now suppose

```
node 1 is associated with cluster head 11.
node 2 with cluster head 12.
node 3 with cluster head 11.
node 4 with cluster head 11.
node 5 with cluster head 12.
```

What I need is to maintain array such as

```
 Table_cluster(11)={1,2....,3*256} %% 1,2,...,3*256 indicates position . Data can be any.
 Table_cluster(12)={1,2....,2*256}
```

I tried to find out that how can I convert position of array in another array which holds dynamic size.But I can not find it out.

So please help or suggest me any other way to achieve my concept.

Comment: Your examples are not quite clear to me. I understand that 1*256 means it's a position. "Data can be any" what does it mean?

Comment: Means 3*256 are the positions and those positions can contain any numeric data.

Comment: okay. So you want to create arrays which are of size 3*256, 1*256 etc.? From `Table_cluster(11)`. Also, how are you getting the all the positions i mean where are you currently storing it? In an array or cell?

Comment: Yes.But not from Table_cluster(11),To Table_cluster(11). Because any clusterhead has any numbers of nodes and each node will send 256 bytes of data. So if cluster head is 11 and it has 3 nodes than It will get 3*256 bytes . So I need to that Table_cluster(11) will hold {1,2,3.... upto.....3*256}.

Comment: In my case I am using one loop such from 1 to 100 nodes. In that loop I am getting data in one array of 256 bytes. Then I have to send to cluster head.Which will aggregate data from all associated nodes.

Comment: Do something like this - ` Table_cluster{11}=[1,2....,3*256]`, `Table_cluster{12}=[1,2....,2*256]` and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, you need to store arrays into another array. This means your `Table_cluster` is going to be a cell array.

Inside your table cluster, you can store a cell of 2D arrays. In your case, the 2D arrays are actually of size 1x256 2x256, etc. (if I understand right). This is where your Cluster heads are aggregating them. To do this, you need to read about MATLAB cell arrays and how to index them. As @Divakar pointed out in his comment, the cell array indexing is different than that of a 1-D or 2D array. You have {} braces to do the indexing.